# select retornando em branco sendo que já inseri coisas no banco (php com msql)

Tags: php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguem pode me ajudar não sei pq não esta aparecendo o resultado na pagina

Comment: Queira [edit] trocar a imagem por código, facilita para podermos ajudar. Pode até deixar o screenshot do resultado, mas o código em texto é importante. E descreva também qual é o resultado que deveria ter aparecido.

Comment: Onde está a conexão com o banco? E também não vi a função para executar a query que você fez.

Comment: O nome do seu campo no banco é campo1 mesmo?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa conectar ao banco e executar a query.

Para conectar seria algo como:

```
function conectar()
{
    try
    {
        //Localhost
        $host = "localhost";
        $user = "root";
        $password = "";
        $database = "nomedobanco";

        $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);            
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        die("Erro de conexão: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    return $conn;
}
```

E para executar algo como:

```
function listar()
{
    $link = conectar();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tablea";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

    return $result;
}
```